Landscape mode and videoView in android studio
I wrote a program that when I run this program on the phone, a video will start playing.
Now, after the video is played, if I rotate my phone to landscape mode, my app also rotates to landscape mode, but the video plays from the beginning, which is a problem for me.

package com.example.videoview

import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.MediaController
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.videoview.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private var position = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        initVideoView()

    }

    private fun initVideoView() {

        val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/${R.raw.paris_video}")

        val controller = MediaController(this)

        binding.videoView.setMediaController(controller)

        binding.videoView.setVideoURI(uri)

        binding.videoView.start()

        binding.videoView.setOnPreparedListener {

            it.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener { _, _, _ ->

                controller.setAnchorView(binding.videoView)

            }

        }

    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

        outState.putInt("position", binding.videoView.currentPosition)

    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position")

        binding.videoView.seekTo(position)

    }

}


I wrote the code that when I rotate the phone to landscape mode and my app also rotates to landscape mode so that the video does not play from the beginning, but I don't know why it doesn't work properly.

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

        outState.putInt("position", binding.videoView.currentPosition)

    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position")

        binding.videoView.seekTo(position)

    }



Your implementation of onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState seems correct.
However, Check if the onRestoreInstanceState is called after orientation change.
    binding.videoView.setOnPreparedListener {
        it.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener { _, _, _ ->
            controller.setAnchorView(binding.videoView)
        }

        // Check if savedInstanceState is not null and contains position
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("position")) {
            position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position")
            binding.videoView.seekTo(position)
        }

        binding.videoView.start()
    }

Move binding.videoView.start() inside the setOnPreparedListener.
And Chech if savedInstanceState is not null and contains the position then seeks to the saved position before starting the video.
